# Nesting of #/% in clojure macros

Tags: macros, clojure

I know that nesting #,% is bad -- however, I often find myself writing short, online anonymous functions that ends up having exactly 2 levels of #/%'s.

Thus, I'm curious, is there a way to tell clojure something where each % is bound to the nearest (smallest enclosing) #?

Thanks!

Comment: I read this twice, but can't quite understand what your question is.  Could you please clarify it?  It will probably help you get a more useful answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nesting of anonymous functions is not supported in clojure.

Edit:  By "anonymous functions" I meant `#(...)`, not `(fn ...)`.  Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: `(((fn [x] (fn [y] [x y])) 1) 2)`

Comment: that is not correct as danlei shows. Nested use of the #(...) reader macro for anonymous functions is not supported; nesting using 'fn' is fine.

Comment: Yes, of course.  My comment was directed at the reader macro, which was the subject of the question.

Comment: To all the down votes: imho, the misuse of "anonymous functions" is not Alex's fault -- it's my fault since in the original question, I confused #( ... % ... ) w/ anonymous functions.

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer Alex, it makes more sense now. I suspected that you were referring to the reader macro, but it's good to be clear about it. :)

Answer (score 8):

Having nested anonymous functions is perfectly fine. You just have to use the non-shorthand syntax.

```
#(foo (bar %1)
      (baz %2))
```

is equivalent to

```
(fn [x y]
  (foo (bar x)
       (bax y)))
```

The full variant can be nested arbitrarily. Also, if you tend to use `map` with `fn` lot, consider using `for` instead (which tend to look clearer in my opinion):

```
(map (fn [row]
       (map (fn [col]
              (+ (* 10 row) col))
            (range 3)))
     (range 3))
```

does the same thing as

```
(for [row (range 3)]
  (for [col (range 3)]
    (+ (* 10 row) col)))
```